# dynamic type can't return from web api always different set of columns

Tags: c#, dynamic

My issue is this.
[image]

I have an ever changing set of columns due to pivoting on a list of items in a table.  Basically each column that you see in the above picture is a line in the database table. I want to display a group of lines as one line on the front end.  How do I return this dynamic type from a controller or api?

I have been attempting to use code such as this.

```
List<dynamic> items = repository.GetAll();
foreach(var item in items){
var properties = item.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public);
   foreach (var property in properties) {
       var PropertyName = property.Name;
       var PropertyValue =    item.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(item, null);
       model.Add(PropertyName, PropertyValue);
   }
}
```

But GetProperties() returns nothing from the dynamic "item".  I've also tried using item.GetType().GetFields() to no avail.
How can i go about getting the column name and value from a dynamic data type in c# when i don't know the name of that column? Or just returning the dynamic object from the api?  Thanks.

Here's the repository code.

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetAll()
{
var items = context.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>(
                   "DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)" +

        "SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(FormDetails.Name)" +
               "     from Value" +
       " left join ValueDetails" +
       " on Value.Id = ValueDetails.ValueId" +
       " left" +
                 "   join FormDetails" +


                 "  on ValueDetails.FormDetailsId = FormDetails.Id" +
                 "         ORDER BY 1" +
                 "  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE" +
                 "   ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')" +

                 " SET @sql = 'SELECT Id, FormId, CreatedDateTime, ' + @cols + '" +
                 "     FROM" +
                 "   (" +
                  "    select Value.Id, Value.FormId, FormDetails.Name, ValueDetails.Value, Value.CreatedDateTime" +

                  "      from Value" +
                  "      left join ValueDetails" +

                   "     on Value.Id = ValueDetails.ValueId" +

                    "    left" +
                  "      join FormDetails" +

                 "  on ValueDetails.FormDetailsId = FormDetails.Id" +
                  "  ) s" +
                 "   PIVOT" +
                    "(" +
                      "MAX(Value) FOR Name IN(' + @cols + ')" +
                    ") p order by CreatedDateTime desc '" +

       " EXECUTE(@sql)").ToList();
        return items;
}
```

Here's a bit more info.  Basically my repository returns the data from the first image at the top of this page.  But when i return that data to the front end this is what it looks like.  The object is there but no properties...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is not in getting an empty list of properties, because they are genuinely not there. `SqlQuery<T>` will not populate a property if it's not there on type `T`; you are passing `dynamic`, which translates to `System.Object`.

One trick to solving this is to retrieve column names dynamically, and build an `ExpandoObject` out of it. The technique is described [here](http://lvasquez.github.io/2013/08/15/return-dynamic-result-from-database-asp-mvc/).

```
static IList<dynamic> Read(DbDataReader reader) {
    var res= new List<Dictionary<string,object>>();
    foreach (var item in reader) {
        IDictionary<string,object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(item)) {
            var obj = propertyDescriptor.GetValue(item);
            expando.Add(propertyDescriptor.Name, obj);
        }
        res.Add(expando);
    }
    return res;
}
```

With this method in place, call

```
using (var cmd = ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand()) {
    ctx.Database.Connection.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = ...; // Your big SQL goes here
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        return Read(reader).ToList();
    }
}
```

Once your repository start returning `ExpandoObject`s, your code for retrieving properties can be replaced with code querying `IDictionary<string,object>`, an interface implemented by `ExpandoObject`:

```
IDictionary<string,object> properties = item as IDictionary<string,object>;
if (properties != null) {
    foreach (var p in properties) {
        model.Add(p.Key, p.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'l give this a shot and let you know what happens.  Thanks.

Comment: Omg that works.  Thanks so much.  2 days of banging my head against the wall.  I guess the reader couldn't interpret the properties of the dynamic item?

Comment: @joel1618 Under the hood there is no such thing as `dynamic` (that's what Servy was trying to hint). When you write `dynamic` C# sticks `object` in its place, but lets the code that uses unknown methods and properties compile, assuming that you would supply an implementation at run-time. When you call `SqlQuery<T>`, it is both the properties of `T` and the column names in the query that decide what columns will be returned. For example, `SqlQuery<T>` sees that query returns `FormId`, so it looks for `FormId` on `T`, which is `dynamic`, i.e. `object`. `FormId` is not there, so it gets skipped.

Comment: Gotcha.  So my issue was with the SqlQuery<dynamic> code primarily.  Makes sense.  Thanks for the help!